# dashed or dotted brace or bracket

Tags: fonts, pdftex, metafont, calligraphy

I need to add a dashed or dotted brace or bracket into an equation. But I didn't found any symbol similar to this (with detexify or The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List).

Do you know how it can be done?

Answer (score 6):

It can be drawn with TikZ by combining a dashed line with a brace decoration like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [dashed, decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt}] (0,0) -- (0,2);
\draw [dashed, decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt}] (2,2) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: DashedBraces]

Comment: Thanks. it helps me a lot. I just wonder how do get the same with calligraphic curved parenthesis from the calligraphy library. I tried but the result is not fully dashed : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202461/dashed-calligraphic-curved-parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a solution using Metafont to create those dashed parenthesis.

Here's my code (wich could certainly be improved) to use with 12pt fonts:

```
u#:=23.5/36pt#;
define_pixels(u);

beginchar(40,7u#,16u#,5u#);"left dashed parenthesis";
x1=x9=6.5u;
x2=x8;x3=x7;
x4=x6;
bot y1=-5u; 
top y9=h;
z10=(17u,5.5u);
(x2,y2)=(x1,y1) rotatedaround (z10,-8.5);
(x3,y3)=(x1,y1) rotatedaround (z10,-17);
(x4,y4)=(x1,y1) rotatedaround (z10,-33);
(x5,y5)=(x1,y1) rotatedaround (z10,-45);
(x6,y6)=(x1,y1) rotatedaround (z10,-57);
(x7,y7)=(x1,y1) rotatedaround (z10,-73);
(x8,y8)=(x1,y1) rotatedaround (z10,-81.5);
penpos1(1.5u,0);
penpos2(1.5u,0);
penpos3(1.5u,0);
penpos4(1.5u,0);
penpos5(1.5u,0);
penpos6(1.5u,0);
penpos7(1.5u,0);
penpos8(1.5u,0);
penpos9(1.5u,0);
  pickup pencircle;
 penstroke z1e..z2e..z3e; 
penstroke z4e..z5e{up}..z6e;
 penstroke z7e..z8e..z9e;
 labels(range 1 thru 10);
 endchar;


beginchar(41,7u#,16u#,5u#);"right dashed parenthesis";
x1=x9=0.5u;
x2=x8;x3=x7;
x4=x6;
bot y1=-5u; 
top y9=h;
z10=(-10u,5.5u);
(x2,y2)=(x1,y1) rotatedaround (z10,8.5);
(x3,y3)=(x1,y1) rotatedaround (z10,17);
(x4,y4)=(x1,y1) rotatedaround (z10,33);
(x5,y5)=(x1,y1) rotatedaround (z10,45);
(x6,y6)=(x1,y1) rotatedaround (z10,57);
(x7,y7)=(x1,y1) rotatedaround (z10,73);
(x8,y8)=(x1,y1) rotatedaround (z10,81.5);
penpos1(1.5u,0);
penpos2(1.5u,0);
penpos3(1.5u,0);
penpos4(1.5u,0);
penpos5(1.5u,0);
penpos6(1.5u,0);
penpos7(1.5u,0);
penpos8(1.5u,0);
penpos9(1.5u,0);
  pickup pencircle;
 penstroke z1e..z2e..z3e; 
penstroke z4e..z5e{up}..z6e;
 penstroke z7e..z8e..z9e;
 labels(range 1 thru 10);
 endchar;
  end
```

You can see the result in LaTeX
[image]

Thanks to [this tutorial from Christophe Grandsire](http://metafont.tutorial.free.fr/downloads/mftut.pdf)