# dashed calligraphic curved parenthesis

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, calligraphy

I tried to get a dashed curved brace but I didn't got exactly what I expected.
Here is the code I used and the result below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calligraphy}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [dashed, decorate, decoration={calligraphic curved parenthesis, amplitude=10pt}] (0,0) -- (0,2);
\draw [dashed, decorate , decoration={calligraphic curved parenthesis , amplitude=10pt}] (2,2) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Does anybody know why the brace is not fully dashed like in the example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202263/dashed-or-dotted-brace-or-bracket/202454#202454)?

I guess it's a compatibility problem between dashed option and calligraphy library.

Thanks in advance

Comment: May be the only part dash-able is that middle vertical part. May be the top and bottom are a different path with no option to be dashed, just a decoration.

Answer (score 3):

(I've only just seen this, sorry.)

Manuel's comment is quite right: the upper and lower parts are not dash-able as they are actually filled paths, not stroked paths. This is because they taper and that's not possible with ordinary paths. Implementing a dashed option would be quite tricky as it would involve decomposing a beziér curve according to path-length so isn't something I'll be attempting any time soon.

So, ultimately, yes, this is due to an incompatibility between the calligraphy library and the dash option.