# Dashed or dotted scalable right brace in math mode wanted

Tags: math-mode, scaling, braces, parentheses

How to to typeset a right brace which scales similarly to the left one in the "cases" environment and is dashed or dotted at the same time?
The code below is almost ok---except that the curly bracket is not dashed. In the image below, it was dashed manually. The mathematical object inside the scaled parentheses is an array of two-three lines of varying height. (The tikz right-brace from [dashed or dotted brace or bracket](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202263/dashed-or-dotted-brace-or-bracket) is difficult to automatically get of the same size as the preceding right parenthesis and at the same vertical position. At least I don't know how to do that.)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mleftright,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\(\ldots\text{some consequence}\ldots\ \Leftarrow\)
{\abovedisplayskip=0ex\belowdisplayskip=0ex%
\begin{equation}\label{A}
\mleft.\mleft(
\begin{array}{c}
\text{some condition in the 1st line}\\
\text{another condition in the 2nd line}
\end{array}
\mright).\quad \mright\}
\end{equation}}\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}

Later we refer to \eqref{A}.
\end{document}
```

[image: goal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do it, in a slightly different way.  I define `\dashlbrc` and `\dashrbrc` using the OP's cited question, and then use  `\scaleleftright{}{}{}` from my `scalerel` package to get them to scale to the size of the central material.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mleftright,amsmath,tikz,scalerel}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\def\dshlbrc{\tikz{%
  \draw [dashed, decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt}] (0,0) -- (0,2);
  }%
}
\def\dshrbrc{\tikz{%
  \draw [dashed, decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt}] (2,2) -- (2,0);
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\(\ldots\text{some consequence}\ldots\ \Leftarrow\)
{\abovedisplayskip=0ex\belowdisplayskip=0ex%
\begin{equation}\label{A}
\scaleleftright{.}{\mleft(
\begin{array}{c}
\text{some condition in the 1st line}\\
\text{another condition in the 2nd line}
\end{array}
\mright).\quad}{\dshrbrc}
\end{equation}}\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}

Later we refer to \eqref{A}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @steven-b-segletes: Thanks a lot, works for me, upvoting!