# dotted or dashed brackets in bmatrix pmatrix

Tags: amsmath, matrices

I'd welcome versions of the `bmatrix` and `pmatrix` environments that dash or dot the brackets.  A MWE is below.  I found [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202263/dashed-or-dotted-brace-or-bracket) that explains how to draw dashed curly braces, but I'd like an environment that behaves in every way like `bmatrix` or `pmatrix` except for the dashed pattern.  How would I accomplish that?  My guess is that bmatrix is much easier than pmatrix.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 \\ 2& 3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
I want the brackets of this matrix dashed or densely dotted.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I have seen this before but I can't remember which question...

Comment: Different from the one I'm referring to?

Comment: Yes -- a matrix with dashed delimiters... perhaps in a package documentation. I think the math experts will know...

Comment: That would be great.

Comment: Perhaps a tikz - matrix based solution would do as well?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Maybe this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202263/dashed-or-dotted-brace-or-bracket

Comment: That's the one referred to in my question.

Comment: Do they have to be dashed brackets or can they just be vertical dashed lines? The `arydshln` package can do that with `\begin{array}{:cc:}0&1\\2&3\end{array}`.

Comment: Please see the extended part that I added to my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See below for expanded answer.

Here is the `dBmatrix` and `dpmatrix` environments, using code from the cited question and the `environ` package.  My `tikz` is primitive, so I am still trying to figure out how to get bracket decorations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,environ}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy}
\NewEnviron{dBmatrix}{\setbox0=\hbox{$\,\begin{matrix}\BODY\end{matrix}\,$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [dashed, thick, decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}] (0,\botdim)--(0,\topdim);
    \copy0
    \draw [dashed, thick, decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}] (0,\topdim)--(0,\botdim);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  \vcenter{\hbox{\copy2}}}
\NewEnviron{dpmatrix}{\setbox0=\hbox{$\,\begin{matrix}\BODY\end{matrix}\,$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [dashed, thick, decorate, decoration={calligraphic straight parenthesis, amplitude=1pt}] (0,\botdim)--(0,\topdim);
    \copy0
    \draw [dashed, thick, decorate, decoration={calligraphic straight parenthesis, amplitude=1pt}] (0,\topdim)--(0,\botdim);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  \vcenter{\hbox{\copy2}}}
\def\topdim{\dimexpr+\ht0+.5\ht\strutbox-.5\dp\strutbox-3pt\relax}
\def\botdim{\dimexpr-\ht0+.5\ht\strutbox-.5\dp\strutbox+3pt\relax}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{Bmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\ 2& 3
\end{Bmatrix}%
\quad
\begin{dBmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\ 2& 3
\end{dBmatrix}
\]
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\ 2& 3\\4 & 5
\end{pmatrix}%
\quad
\begin{dpmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\ 2& 3\\4& 5
\end{dpmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Employing Peter Grill's answer at [draw round/rectangular bracket embracing nodes in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203821/draw-round-rectangular-bracket-embracing-nodes-in-tikz) allowed for the definition of rounded parens as well as square bracket decorations.  Thus, the look here is slightly different than above.  So here, `dpmatrix` is redefined from above and `dbmatrix` is introduced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,environ}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy,calc}
\tikzset{
    ncbar angle/.initial=90,
    ncbar/.style={
        to path=(\tikztostart)
        -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
        -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
    ncbar/.default=0.5cm,
}

\tikzset{square left brace/.style={ncbar=0.5ex}}
\tikzset{square right brace/.style={ncbar=-0.5ex}}

\tikzset{round left paren/.style={ncbar=0.3cm,out=115,in=-115}}
\tikzset{round right paren/.style={ncbar=0.3cm,out=65,in=-65}}
%
\NewEnviron{dBmatrix}{\setbox0=\hbox{$\,\begin{matrix}\BODY\end{matrix}\,$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [dashed, thick, decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}] (0,\botdim)--(0,\topdim);
    \copy0
    \draw [dashed, thick, decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=5pt}] (0,\topdim)--(0,\botdim);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  \vcenter{\hbox{\copy2}}%
}
\NewEnviron{dpmatrix}{\setbox0=\hbox{$\,\begin{matrix}\BODY\end{matrix}\,$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [dashed, thick] (0,\botdim) to [round left paren] (0,\topdim);
    \copy0
    \draw [dashed, thick] (0,\botdim) to [round right paren] (0,\topdim);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  \vcenter{\hbox{\copy2}}%
}
\NewEnviron{dbmatrix}{\setbox0=\hbox{$\,\begin{matrix}\BODY\end{matrix}\,$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [dashed, thick] (0,\botdim) to [square left brace] (0,\topdim);
    \copy0
    \draw [dashed, thick] (0,\botdim) to [square right brace] (0,\topdim);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  \vcenter{\hbox{\copy2}}%
}
\def\topdim{\the\dimexpr+\ht0+.5\ht\strutbox-.5\dp\strutbox-3pt\relax}
\def\botdim{\the\dimexpr-\ht0+.5\ht\strutbox-.5\dp\strutbox+3pt\relax}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{Bmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\ 2& 3
\end{Bmatrix}%
\quad
\begin{dBmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\ 2& 3
\end{dBmatrix}
\]
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\ 2& 3\\4 & 5
\end{pmatrix}%
\quad
\begin{dpmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\ 2& 3\\4& 5
\end{dpmatrix}
\]
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\ 2& 3
\end{bmatrix}%
\quad
\begin{dbmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\ 2& 3
\end{dbmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]