# Customizing square brackets

Tags: amsmath, brackets, cases, mathtools

I am trying to modify LaTeX's brackets (`\cases`) to make something like the one on the left:

[image: click here]

I could only find code for square box and brackets (`\cases`), but not for this particular variant on any forums. The problem is how to either how to add a "tip" on `[` or straighten up the corners on `\cases`.
Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can upload png files. Without the picture, it is hard to find out what you want.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [this advanced answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111802)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER**: This is almost entirely taken from [Steven B. Segletes answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327584/121799) and what I made here is also more a matrix that can be abused for cases. But the upshot is that with Steven's code one can draw any bracket one wants after very simple adjustments. Of course, some basic knowledge of Ti*k*Z helps.

```
\documentclass{article} % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327584/121799
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,environ}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\tikzset{
    ncbar angle/.initial=90,
    ncbar/.style={
        to path=(\tikztostart)
        -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
        -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
    ncbar/.default=0.5cm,
    freaky dim/.default=4pt,
    freaky/.style={
        to path={let \p1=(\tikztostart),\p2=(\tikztotarget) in (\tikztostart)
        -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ({\x1-#1},{(\y1+\y2)/2-abs(#1)})
        -- ({\x1-2*#1},{(\y1+\y2)/2})
        -- ({\x1-#1},{(\y1+\y2)/2+abs(#1)})
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
        -- (\tikztotarget)}
    },
    freaky/.default=0.5cm,
}

\tikzset{freaky left brace/.style={freaky=0.5ex}}
\tikzset{freaky right brace/.style={freaky=-0.5ex}}

\tikzset{square left brace/.style={ncbar=0.5ex}}
\tikzset{square right brace/.style={ncbar=-0.5ex}}

\tikzset{round left paren/.style={ncbar=0.3cm,out=115,in=-115}}
\tikzset{round right paren/.style={ncbar=0.3cm,out=65,in=-65}}
%

\NewEnviron{flcases}{\setbox0=\hbox{$\,\begin{matrix}\BODY\end{matrix}\,$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [thick] (0,\botdim) to [freaky left brace] (0,\topdim);
    \copy0
  \end{tikzpicture}}
  \vcenter{\hbox{\copy2}}%
}


\def\topdim{\the\dimexpr+\ht0+.5\ht\strutbox-.5\dp\strutbox-3pt\relax}
\def\botdim{\the\dimexpr-\ht0+.5\ht\strutbox-.5\dp\strutbox+3pt\relax}
\begin{document}

\[ f(x)=
\begin{flcases}
   0 & \text{if}~x<0  \\ 
   \pi & \text{if}~x\ge0  
\end{flcases}%
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks. Segletes's code (you referred to ) works like charm. I'm still trying to comprehend his code and tweak it for my own use though.